# Phoenix 1.3 migration unknown application:

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to migrate my Phoenix app from 1.2 to 1.3 using the [official guide](http://phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-120-to-130), including moving the web code into lib/my_app_web.

I am hitting the following

```
== Compilation error on file lib/my_app_web/gettext.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) unknown application: :MyAppWeb
    (elixir) lib/application.ex:428: Application.app_dir/1
    (elixir) lib/application.ex:437: Application.app_dir/2
    (gettext) expanding macro: Gettext.Compiler.__before_compile__/1
    lib/my_app_web/gettext.ex:1: MyAppWeb.Gettext (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

in `lib/my_app_web.ex` I define `defmodule MyAppWeb do ... end`

Is there something else I need to update?

Comment: You probably need to pass the name of the application which is `:my_app_web` most likely.

Comment: thanks, where is that passed?

Comment: Is there an instance of `:MyAppWeb` in `lib/my_app_web/gettext.ex`? Try changing that to `:my_app_web`.

Answer (score 0):

Recent I came across this error. But not totally the same with you:
    I need to read some static file after compiled, 
so I use the  `Application.app_dir(:my_app, "priv/cert")` to get the static file path in compiled release.
But I find the error when compiled:

```
** (ArgumentError) unknown application: :my_app
```

Finally I find this error caused by the reason that I put `Application.app_dir(:my_app, "priv/cert")` in the `config/dev.exs`.
When `mix` reading the `config file`, the `:my_app` still not exist.
So this error occured.